Any Neovim plugins for formatting Markdown text?
I started learning Vim because I spend too much time formatting text right in Markdown editors. Vim motions help a lot with that, but I still want hotkeys or motions to format text in markdown to bold italic etc.
Before I would think of implementing these in my own configuration, I would be surprised if there weren't any Neovim plugins to do this. I found Markdown LSPs and plugins like Markdown Vim mode but none specific for using hotkeys or motions to format text.
Here's a page on Basic Syntax for Markdown.

Hotkeys to change selected text to **bold** *italic*, _italic_ `inline code` etc.

## Headings as well (any level from 1 to 6, # to ######)
Add links to them: [selected text](cursor position to write the link)
and inline code obviously.


> blockquotes, was well as indenting and outdenting them. indenting would be from > text to >> text.

Same thing with - bullet points.

Creating blank callouts and putting selecting text in callouts.
> [!callout label] title
> callout text or selected text.


Same thing with code blocks
``` cursor position (so I can specify the programming or markup language for syntax highlighting)
selected text
```




Don't know if there's a plugin to do it all. Seems like a bunch of rather easy mappings. Sooner or later, somebody will suggest surround.vim for bold, italic, etc. so I might as well do it now. As for headings, bullet points and block quotes: can't get much easier than I# <Esc>, can it?

I just listed a bunch of markdown formatting to get whatever answers I can.

There may be partial answers but these are discouraged (and you barred putting a bunch of mappings in your config). From that point, your question lacks focus. On the other hand, they're all typical markdown editing tasks so they're best kept together. I'm a bit at loss how this could be answered.

Related: Convenient way to surround block with markdown codeblock backticks

Plugin requests are off-topic here. See [help/on-topic] and [edit] if you can refocus this question.

I’m voting to close this question because plugin requests are off-topic.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allows the question to rest :-)

The VimWiki plugin support the markdown syntax on top of its own syntax.
It comes with a number of mappings that help editing markdown files in particular:

headings
list
table

They are documented.
For the typeface support I would recommend using vim-surround
E.g:

To put selection in Italic you could do: S_
To remove italic from the selection you could do: ds_


I said somebody would bring up surround, didn't I?

I appreciate the gesture. I can hardly take credit for mentioning the (probably?) most popular Vim plugin ever. And I don't even use surround myself. I kept forgetting the mappings and had to look them up every time so I stopped using it years ago :-D
